# Linux audio routing without Jack

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, oss

Is it possible to do linux audio without using Jack for audio routing?

Can I route using Alsa or OSS?

Comment: If it were possible, why does Jack exist?

Comment: @CL: AFAIK one of the most important reasons for creating Jack was low-latency audio processing. The routing is just icing on the cake.

Answer (score 0):

You can do various things with ALSA plugins that I would describe as "routing", though it's not a basic concept in ALSA like it is in jack. For most concrete situations (you didn't mention if you have a concrete situation), you can cobble something together.

You can definitely route in Pulseaudio, it's a basic concept.

OSS is so old and depracted that I've never used it. From the little I know about it, I doubt you can do any routing with it.